# Is there a way to find the size of a visible part of an image within an ImageView?

Tags: java, android, imageview, png, pixel

I'm looking for a way to find the dimensions of the *visible* part of an image is. The image I'm displaying in my `ImageView` is .png format, it has a portion that is "visible" and the rest is an invisible background.

Example Image:

[image]
←<sub>that box isn't visible on the real image, it's just to illustrate my point</sub>

So in this image there is only a small red wedge shape which is visible, but the full .png is really a rectangle of larger dimensions, thus I can't use something like `bitmap.getWidth();`

So:

1. How can I find out if a particular pixel in an image is "invisible" or not? Note: I know I can use `bitmap.getPixel(x, y);` to *get* a pixel, but I don't know what to do with it once I have it; is a test for 0 sufficient?
2. Is there a better way of finding the max width/height of the "visible" portion other than iterating through every pixel looking for the visible "end points"?

Answer (score 4):

1. **How can I find out if a particular pixel in an image is "invisible" or not? Note: I know I can use bitmap.getPixel(x, y); to get a pixel, but I don't know what to do with it once I have it; is a test for 0 sufficient?**

   Use `image.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT` to check whether the pixel is visible or not.
2. **Is there a better way of finding the max width/height of the "visible" portion other than iterating through every pixel looking for the visible "end points"?**

   There is no built in functions. You can use the below function to get the image in square shape leaving the transparent pixels out.

   ```
   public static Bitmap removeTransparentPixels(Bitmap image) {

       int x1 = image.getWidth();
       int y1 = image.getHeight();

       int width = 0, height = 0;

       for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
           for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
               if (image.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                   if (x < x1) {
                       x1 = x;
                   } else if (x > width) {
                       width = x;
                   }

                   if (y < y1) {
                       y1 = y;
                   } else if (y > height) {
                       height = y;
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       width = width - x1;
       height = height - y1;

       return Bitmap.createBitmap(image, x1, y1, width, height);
   }
   ```

Make sure that your image doesn't contain only the transparent pixels. If the image has only transparent pixels then the statement `Bitmap.createBitmap(image, x1, y1, width, height);` will through exception.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing, except I send back an array of points instead of generating a new `Bitmap` (I figure that would probably be more costly since I only need the points). I have to do this over and over again for a number of images so I was hoping there was a way I was missing with less impact. Good point about the `Color.TRANSPARENT` wasn't aware of that one!

Comment: i use this method to give me a Rect so i can check if the visible part was touched. I also let the for loop increase by 5 (maybe check for bounds) which speeds things up and precision is still nice

Answer (score 1):

There are probably some form of image processing libraries that you would need to take advantage of in order to achieve what you are requesting in order to keep the processing down if that is a concern such as OpenCV or ImageMagick that would probably get that information back to you in a quick manner via specific function calls.

As far as I know, there wouldn't be a built in way to determine that through a standard call into the image libraries that exist within Android.  You would probably need to do some sort of heuristic check for transparent pixels as you mentioned with your original thought.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I thought, but I'm new to Android so I was hoping that I was wrong. Thanks for the input.